# Terminator always start in a separate workspace after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, terminator

I recently upgraded ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. Now when I open the terminator, it always starts in a separate workspace. I need to switch to that workspace to access the terminator. It was working fine when I had 14.04.

I tried purging and reinstalling terminator also. But still the issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a config file at `~/.config/terminator/config` and it had not been removed even with purge. Removed that file and reinstalled terminator and it is working fine now.